# javascript loop does not write to number input

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have made a loop to several fields in a dynamic table row to write and retrieve data from localstorage.

It first saves data on localstore, resets the table to 0 rows and for retrieval of data, the table rows will be recreated it and load data there. The problem is that when the textbox is of type "number", the field appears blank. It loads data on the respective fields as I tried it on the number field's placeholder values just to see data coming.

This only happens on the looped fields in the dynamic rows of the table. Number inputs from the fixed rows can load properly.

The ID's I used on the loop where correct and prints

`document.getElementById('4-4-1').value = 2"`

Where

```
4-4-1 = x-y-z
x = tableNumber
y = FieldNumber
z = RowNumber
```

But when I pasted `document.getElementById('4-4-1').value` again on the console, it returns nothing. (Though a placeholder of '2' appears on the field).

I also tried changing the value with the same line in the console and it works properly.

Why is it that it is not working on number fields during the loop?

Tried it on Chrome, Firefox. Aiming for Android 4.2 web view.

**The Store Loop**

```
function saveRecordNow() {
var rec = {};
rec[0] = document.getElementById('data0').value
rec[1] = document.getElementById('data1').value
rec[2] = document.getElementById('otherdata').value
rec[3] = document.getElementById('foo').value
...
...
var tblSpaceQtr = document.getElementById('tblSpaceQtr');

rowCnt = tblSpaceQtr.getElementsByTagName("tr").length - 11;  
//there are 11 fixed rows on the table, and is not included on the count


//var page4Data = '';
for(x=1; x <= rowCnt; x++) {
  page4Data += document.getElementById("4-1-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-2-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-3-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-4-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-5-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-6-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-7-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-8-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-9-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-10-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-11-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-12-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-13-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-14-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-15-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-16-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-17-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-18-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-19-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-20-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-21-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-22-"+x).value + ', '+
    document.getElementById("4-23-"+x).value + '||| ';
    //console.log("data from 4-1-"+x);
}
page4Data.substring(0, page4Data.length - 2); //remove end comma
//alert()
rec[681] = page4Data;

...
}
```

***The retrieval loop***

```
function loadRecord(n) {

var getVar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(n));
document.getElementById('id').value = n;
numCells = document.getElementById('nbcells');

document.getElementById('data0').value = getVar[0];
document.getElementById('data1').value = getVar[1];
document.getElementById('otherdata').value = getVar[2];
document.getElementById('foo').value = getVar[3];
document.getElementById('foo2').value = getVar[4];
document.getElementById('foo3').value = getVar[5];
...

initTable(numCells, numCells.value)
var pg4Data = [],
pg4RowData = [],
pg4Data = getVar[681].split('|||');
page4Data = getVar[681]
//getVar[681] from JSON.parse(localStore['source']);
//having a csv separated by '|||' per row

for(x=1; x < pg4Data.length; x++) {
    pg4RowData = pg4Data[x-1].split(',');
    document.getElementById("4-1-"+x).value = pg4RowData[0];    
    document.getElementById("4-2-"+x).value = pg4RowData[1];
    document.getElementById("4-3-"+x).value = pg4RowData[2];
    document.getElementById("4-4-"+x).value = pg4RowData[3];
    console.log("document.getElementById('4-4-"+x+"').value =" +pg4RowData[3]);
        document.getElementById("4-4-"+x).placeholder = pg4RowData[3];
    //document.getElementById("4-4-"+x).setAttribute('value', pg4RowData[3]);   
    //document.getElementById("4-5-"+x).value = pg4RowData[4];
    document.getElementById("4-5-"+x).value = pg4RowData[4];
        document.getElementById("4-5-"+x).placeholder = pg4RowData[4];
    document.getElementById("4-6-"+x).value = pg4RowData[5];
        document.getElementById("4-6-"+x).placeholder = pg4RowData[5];
    document.getElementById("4-7-"+x).value = pg4RowData[6];
        document.getElementById("4-7-"+x).placeholder = pg4RowData[6];
    document.getElementById("4-8-"+x).value = pg4RowData[7];
        document.getElementById("4-8-"+x).placeholder = pg4RowData[7];
    document.getElementById("4-9-"+x).value = pg4RowData[8];
        document.getElementById("4-9-"+x).placeholder = pg4RowData[8];
    document.getElementById("4-10-"+x).value = pg4RowData[9];
    document.getElementById("4-11-"+x).value = pg4RowData[10];
    document.getElementById("4-12-"+x).value = pg4RowData[11];
    document.getElementById("4-13-"+x).value = pg4RowData[12];
    document.getElementById("4-14-"+x).value = pg4RowData[13];
    document.getElementById("4-15-"+x).value = pg4RowData[14];
    document.getElementById("4-16-"+x).value = pg4RowData[15];
    document.getElementById("4-17-"+x).value = pg4RowData[16];
    document.getElementById("4-18-"+x).value = pg4RowData[17];
    document.getElementById("4-19-"+x).value = pg4RowData[18];
    document.getElementById("4-20-"+x).value = pg4RowData[19];
    document.getElementById("4-21-"+x).value = pg4RowData[20];
    document.getElementById("4-22-"+x).value = pg4RowData[21];
    document.getElementById("4-23-"+x).value = pg4RowData[22];
}
...
}
```

Comment: Please create a reduced test case that completely demonstrates the problem. It needs to include some of the HTML and the mechanism by which the script is loaded. A live example of JSBin or JSFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Just a reminder for HTML4: `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`

Comment: any chances that pg4RowData is not what you are expecting it to be?

Comment: @GuardianX no, it pops the correct data on the respective fields esp. as placeholder text on number fields, not on their values. I used the placeholders for visibility of data.

Comment: @GuardianX arghh I take back what I said!! It was the split all along. should have made it `split(', ');`  with the space. My mistake

Answer (score 0):

The element's IDs, class names, and variables in JavaScript **cannot start with a number**! Please prefix the values with a character and then try it again.

```
for(x=1; x < pg4Data.length; x++) {
    pg4RowData = pg4Data[x-1].split(',');
    document.getElementById("s-4-1-"+x).value = pg4RowData[0];    
    document.getElementById("s-4-2-"+x).value = pg4RowData[1];
    document.getElementById("s-4-3-"+x).value = pg4RowData[2];
    document.getElementById("s-4-4-"+x).value = pg4RowData[3];
```

Comment: Hi @Praveen, I tried doing it like `document.getElementById("row4-1-"+x)`, but no good on browser. I executed the command on the chrome console and it changed the value so I still think it's the loop. I also tried changing the field type to 'text' when the field is created and it works. Meanwhile, I'll try to do a JSFiddle when I can. Thank you everyone for answering

Comment: @niCad Yes, doing a jsFiddle will be a good idea. I am waiting for the fiddle, so that we can check out what's the problem!